# Filter DataGridView Using CheckBox

Tags: vb.net

My Filter DataGridView Using CheckBox does not work when I click on Button1. Pls give me the solution. I attach my code Below :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EmployeeTBDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'EmployeeTBDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmployeeTBDataSet.Table1)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim query As String = ""
        Dim c1check As Boolean

        Dim myList As New List(Of String)
        For Each cb As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
            ' we can know if checkbox in GroupBox1 is checked or not
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                c1check = True
                ' get the text of checkbox that checked by user
                myList.Add(cb.Text)
            End If
        Next

        If c1check Then
            ' if checkbox in groupbox1 is checked, we will create this query to our database
            query = "SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Status='" & String.Join("' or Status=" + "'", myList) + "'"
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Filter DataGridView Using CheckBox]

Comment: Your description of your problem is inadequate. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which MUST contain a description of exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what does happen. That said, surely `If CheckBox1.Checked Then` should be `If cb.Checked Then`. You really need to learn how to debug your code properly, i.e. using breakpoints and stepping through the code.

Comment: Looking more closely, your `Button's` `Click` event handler doesn't actually do anything useful.  It builds a query but it never executes it, which is useless.  There's no point executing a query anyway, if you already have all the data.  Just set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` bound to your grid.